# how to update a record in database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm trying to make update to a record in my database . i tried to make it several times but it seem to be the url is the problem can anyone help 
that's my controller method :

```
public function postEditCategory($id,Request $request) {
    $name=$request->input('name');
    DB::table('category')->where('id',$id)->update(['name'=>$name]);
    return redirect('category');
}
```

and that's is my view :

```
<form action="category/Edit-category/{{$cat->id}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-code">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$cat->name}}"></td>
    <td><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update Category</button></td>
</form>
```

and that's my route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    // your routes here
    Route::controller("home" , "homeController");
    Route::controller("slideshow" , "slideshowController");
    Route::controller("products" , "productsController");
    Route::controller("category" , "categoryController");
    Route::controller("product_image" , "productImageController");
    Route::controller("product_detail" , "productDetailController");
    Route::controller("team" , "teamController");

        // Authentication routes...
    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

    // Registration routes...
    Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
});
```

Comment: What does your routes file look like?  What error are you getting?

Comment: @Jeff Controller method not found. that's the error i get and that's the url : http://localhost/Admin/public/category/Edit-category/1

Comment: Have you tried `category/editCategory/{{$cat->id}}`? I haven't seen the kebab-case before in resource controllers

Comment: @Jeff it gave me the same error

Comment: Try just with lowercase `edit-category`. Also, be aware that `Route::controller` is going away in Laravel 5.2, so you may want to code the routes manually

Comment: @Jeff the same , i even tried {{action('categoryController@postEditCatgory',$cat->id)}} and it didn't work too

Comment: please post your route registration in your routes file, very important piece of this puzzle

Comment: and that's my route : Route::controller("category" , "categoryController");

Comment: @Jeff i update my question and but the route file check it

Comment: Thank you.  What happens if you remove the hidden input method type of _PATCH?  If this is sending a patch request maybe it is looking for `patchEditCategory()`

Comment: it worked very well when i removed the hidden input thank u :)